# python file seek skips lines

Tags: python, file, seek

I have a file with content:

```
0x11111111
0x22222222
0x33333333
0x44444444
```

And I'm reading it line by line using:

```
f = open('test1', 'r')
print "Register CIP_REGS_CONTROL value:"
for i in range(4):
    content = f.read(11)
    f.seek(11, 1)
    print content
```

Note that there're 11 bytes each line due to the '\n' char at the end. But the output is:

```
0x11111111

0x33333333
```

There's an empty line after the 1st and 3rd line, I don't know why it's like that. If I delete the '\n' in each line, and change the size of reading and seeking to 10, I got:

```
0x11111111
0x33333333
```

2 lines are also missing. Anybody can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are seeking past the second and fourth lines.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: You're reading 11 characters, and then you're seeking past another 11 characters.

Comment: You are seeking forward from the current read position. What did you expect to happen instead? `f.read()` moves the read position too, you don't need to manually seek between `f.read()` calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove your seek call. Each call is skipping the next 11 bytes. That is read also moves the current position.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then how to remove the '\n' in each string read in? I only need the pure string, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1. You don't need to `seek` after the `read`. Your position in the file will already be at the next character after the call the `read`.
2. When you call `print`, it will add append a newline (`\n`) to your output.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. And do you know how to get rid of the '\n' in each string? Thanks.

Comment: You can either remove the newline in content using `content.strip('\n')` or `content.replace('\n', '')` before you print it. Or, you can call `print content, ` with the comma at the end to prevent it from adding a newline.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (and safest - it ensures your file gets closed properly) way would be to use a [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) construct, and [`readline()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

```
print "Register CIP_REGS_CONTROL value:"
with open('test1', 'r') as f:
    for i in range(4):
        print f.readline().strip()
```

`strip()` when called with no arguments removes all whitespace (which includes `\n`) from the beginning and end of a string.