# how to access previous line while we are accessing lines one by one in a loop using python?

Tags: python, file

this is my code to print 20 lines at a time but I want to print 20 lines and then i want to start printing from 20th line how can I do that can anyone tell me? please

```
f1=open("sample.txt","r")
last_pos=0
line=0
while True:
    for i,l in enumerate(f1):
        #l=f1.readline()
        if l=="":
            break
        line+=1
        print l
        if line == 20:
            last_pos=f1.tell()
            print(last_pos)
            break
f1.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python file seek skips lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741115/python-file-seek-skips-lines)

Comment: Just a general tip: try to avoid using `l` as a variable name. In most fonts you cant really differentiate between `I`, `l` and `1`, or at least it is really hard

Answer (score 0):

To locate some line, you can use seek() function.

Comment: it points to starting of a file and it starts printing from first line.I want to print the last line of that particular group only